# как атоммизировать сущности при десерриализации из XML

Tags: c#, xml, десериализация

существует следующий (даю сильное упрощение) XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Ticket>
        <Age>70254</Age>
        <ArchiveFlag>вне архива</ArchiveFlag>
        <State>В работе</State>
        <StateID>6</StateID>
        <StateType>Таймер</StateType>
        <TicketID>7</TicketID>
        <TicketNumber>2018121710000019</TicketNumber>
        <Title>Название</Title>
        <Type>Билет на продажу</Type>
        <TypeID>1</TypeID>                                  
  </Ticket>
```

для данного файла сделан класс сущностей на дессериализацию:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Ticket
{  
    public ulong Age { get; set; }
    public string ArchiveFlag { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }  
    public uint StateID { get; set; } 
    public string StateType { get; set; }  
    public ulong TicketID { get; set; }   
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }      
    public string Title { get; set; }      
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public uint TypeID { get; set; }              

}
```

Так как в классе Ticket, более 30 полей, хочется их подсвернуть, но не просто так (сам XML я получаю от сторонней программы, где не могу менять выдаваемый контент).
Видя что по сути

> Age ArchiveFlag TicketID TicketNumber Title Type TypeID

относятся к одной сущности, а:

> State StateID StateType

к другой захотелось переделать:

```
public partial class StateModel
{
    public string State { get; set; }  
    public uint StateID { get; set; } 
    public string StateType { get; set; } 
}
```

следовательно изменяя в классе

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Ticket
{  
    public ulong Age { get; set; }
    public string ArchiveFlag { get; set; }
    public StateModel State { get; set; }          
    public ulong TicketID { get; set; }   
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }      
    public string Title { get; set; }      
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public uint TypeID { get; set; }              

}
```

далее дессериализирую:

```
 var node =@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Ticket>
        <Age>70254</Age>
        <ArchiveFlag>вне архива</ArchiveFlag>
        <State>В работе</State>
        <StateID>6</StateID>
        <StateType>Таймер</StateType>
        <TicketID>7</TicketID>
        <TicketNumber>2018121710000019</TicketNumber>
        <Title>Название</Title>
        <Type>Билет на продажу</Type>
        <TypeID>1</TypeID>                                  
  </Ticket>";
 Ticket res;
 using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(node))
 {
      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Ticket));
      res = (Ticket)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      Console.WriteLine($"Статус|{res.State.State}|");
 }
```

получаю пустые значения. Вопрос, как мне реализовать задуманное?

Comment: Надо использовать спец. атрибут, что бы сопоставить StateModel с узлом Ticket в XML.

Comment: @iluxa1810 пробовал XmlElement("State") и XmlAttribute("State"), не получилось!

Comment: Можно в лоб, делать второй класс как вам нравиться, вплоть до обрезки лишних данных, и заполнять его через конструктор 'полным' классом. Не изящно, зато надёжно :) или бороться с атрибутами, но такой тюнинг не будет простым.

Comment: @NewView зачем мне дублировать код? Я как раз наоборот, хочу уменьшить его.

Comment: А пустые значения ты получаешь же в StateModel? Попробуй XmlRoot явно задать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116066/deserialize-with-different-root-element-names

Comment: @iluxa1810 пробовал, не то что мне нужно, у меня нет группировки, поэтому и возникает проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, достаточно использовать наследование, и все будет так как надо:

```
public partial class StateModel
{
   public string State { get; set; }  
   public uint StateID { get; set; } 
   public string StateType { get; set; } 
}

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
 public partial class Ticket:StateModel
 {  
     public ulong Age { get; set; }
     public string ArchiveFlag { get; set; }                  
     public ulong TicketID { get; set; }   
     public string TicketNumber { get; set; }      
     public string Title { get; set; }      
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public uint TypeID { get; set; }              

}
```

И все работает, но тут интересный момент:
Сущностей множество и для некоторых файлов сущности одинаковые. Тогда вопрос решается через интерфейсы (додумался с подсказки от @morphey83)
тогда мы создаем интерфейсы, и последовательно их наследуем:

```
  interface IAge
 {
    ulong Age { get; set; }
    ulong AgeTimeUnix { get; set; }
    string ArchiveFlag { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class TicketAge:IAge
 {
     public ulong Age { get; set; }

     public ulong AgeTimeUnix
     {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
     }
   public string ArchiveFlag { get; set; }
 }

        interface IState
 {
    string State { get; set; }
    uint StateID { get; set; } 
    string StateType { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class TicketState:TicketAge,IState
 {
   public string State { get; set; }  
   public uint StateID { get; set; } 
   public string StateType { get; set; } 
 }

  interface ITicket
 {
    ulong TicketID { get; set; }   
    string TicketNumber { get; set; }      
    string Title { get; set; }      
    string Type { get; set; }
    uint TypeID { get; set; }     
 }
```

и тогда, окончательно класс будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
 public partial class Ticket:TicketState, ITicket
 {                                     
     public ulong TicketID { get; set; }   
     public string TicketNumber { get; set; }      
     public string Title { get; set; }      
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public uint TypeID { get; set; }              

}
```

Теперь у меня все сущности разложены отдельно, и их при необходимости можно править.

Answer (score 2):

Если уж очень хочется, то можно заморочиться с интерфейсом IXmlSerializable, который даст полный контроль над сериализацией/дессериализацией. [почитать тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Но если бы я решал такую задачу, скорее всего использовал бы еще один дата-слой и implicit/explicit операторы

UPD: немного детализирую второй вариант

1. выделяем интерфейсы ITicket, IState и другие из класса сериализации
2. навешиваем их на Ticket
3. создаем новые, красивые классы
4. переливаем данные из одной структуры в другую

новые классы

```
public class State:IState
{
    //  имплементация полей интерфейса IState   
}

public class NewTiket:ITicket
{
    //  имплементация полей интерфейса ITicket  
    //...

    public State State {get;set;}
}
```

теперь, нужно сделать маппинг полей, но мне лень их перечислять - поэтому добавим к нашему вареву немного магии:

```
public static class ObjectExtention
{
    public static void CopyPropertiesFrom<T>(this T source, T target)
    {
        foreach (var info in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            info.SetValue(source, info.GetValue(target, null), null);
    }
}
```

эта функция займется копированием полей (осторожно с ссылочными данными !)

Все, можно переливать данные

```
var result = new NewTiket();
// копируем поля интерфейса ITicket
((ITicket)result).CopyPropertiesFrom(xmlTiket);

result.State  = new State();
// копируем поля интерфейса IState
((IState)result.State).CopyPropertiesFrom(xmlTiket);
```

если этот блок оформить в виде *public static implicit operator NewTiket(Ticket xmlTiket)* в классе NewTicket, то использовать будем так:

```
NewTiket newTiket = xmlTiket;
```

Comment: вообще не понятно о чем вы. Можно пример?

Comment: какое из предложенных решений вас смущает ?

Comment: Похоже на изобретение велосипеда. Не проще ли автомаппер подрубить?

Comment: Неплохое решение, оригинальное

Comment: @NewView, а по моему проще AutoMapper подрубить и он сделат все тоже самое. Если поля имеют одинаковое название, то он автоматически замапит + используется кодогенераци+ к производительности.

Comment: @iluxa1810, соглашусь, AutoMapper правильнее

Comment: @morphey83 немного уточнил вопрос, хочется понять, как применяя ваш совет, должна работать дессериализация.

Comment: @Monomax, Дессериализация работает как и работала - используется тот же класс, что представлен вами в описании. а далее происходит заполнение новой модели. 
Если вы спрашиваете про имплементацию IXmlSerializable, то в этом случае вам предстоит работать напрямую с потоком в момент сериализации и вручную указывать куда необходимо разложить данные. Но в этом случае работа идет через наименование полей, что чревато Runtime ошибками при изменении в модели

Comment: @morphey83 похоже что у нас с вами полное непонимание друг друга. Я речь веду об упрощении класса, а вы мне (как я вижу) предлагаете его перекладывать, в новый класс, это не то.